# One of the VMWARE ESXI machines is not working

Tags: vmware, esxi

One of the machines stopped starting and gives such an error, tell me where to dig?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vSphere 6.5 or 6.7, then it is a known issue as per Vmware and they are still working on it.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/67162

It is difficult to comment without knowing your environment. Generally, you should check if the .vmx file exists in that datastore location and you are able to traverse it using the ESXi command line as well the web client browser. The vmx file itself has not gone corrupt. You should also see if the datastore is reachable and is not showing greyed out in web client or any red sign next to it. If the data store contains any other virtual machines, please check if they have a similar issue.

If other virtual machines are reachable on the same datastore and the concerned VM files are accessible as well, try un-registering and re-registering the VM using the esx console command line, on the same or a different ESXi host. There could several reasons for this issue but primarily it is a communication issue between your ESX host and the storage. ESX logs can also be very helpful in such cases.